# IE11 crashes when started from Visual Studio 2015

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, internet-explorer-11

I just installed VS2015 pro on my recently upgraded windows 10 machine.  I am trying to debug a webpage, specifically the javascript on that page using the debugger in VS.  Before the upgrade I was able to debug the javascript but now when i hit the 'play' button in VS IE11 opens and crashes immediatly.  In the past versions, VS2013 pro and IE10, i was able to hit the 'play' button and was able to step through the code using break points.  I dont get any errors and the website compiles.  i am able to run the website without debugging just fine.  Does anyone know what could be causing the issue that i am having?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can debug IE11 now is, by starting without debugging (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>) until the page loads and then debug (<kbd>F5</kbd>), which takes over the page loaded. Frustrating, but it will get me by until there is a resolution to the issue.

UPDATE-
My project happens to be a Silverlight web app. I started going through the warnings in the build and noticed the following:

*C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Silverlight\v5.0\Microsoft.Ria.Client.targets(303,5): warning : Could not load file or assembly '**System.Windows.Browser**, Version=5.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.*

I found this System.Windows.Browser.dll file in: 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Silverlight\5.1.50709.0
and copied it into the same folder as the reference path to System.Windows:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6

This seemed to have resolved my issue so far.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue after moving to VS2013 and VS2015 on Windows 10.

I found that the debugger was opening IE 64 bit by default. Creating a new IE 32 bit selection solved the problem.

- Open the browser dropdown list in the VS menu bar.
- Click on Browse With..
- Click Add, then browse to C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe
- Enter Internet Explorer 32bit as the friendly name
- Click Set as Default for Internet Explorer 32bit